# creating classes link error

Tags: c++, class

I'm using Dev-C++ 5.2.0.1

I took an example of how to put a class in another file from a website but it resulted in an error.

In the file class.h I have:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
  void foo();
  int bar;
};
```

In the file class.cpp I have:

```
#include "class.h"

void MyClass::foo()
{
    cout<< "test";
}
```

In the file main.cpp I have:

```
#include "class.h" 
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  MyClass a;
  a.foo();
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the error I get:
   [Linker error] C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Local\Temp\cccWe7ee.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `MyClass::foo()' 
   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

New answer.

Are you compiling and linking all of your files together? In gcc you would do something like:

```
gcc -o myExe class.cpp main.cpp
```

I'm not so sure about dev-c++, but I imagine it's not much different.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the files wrongly, I actually did have a class.cpp instead of two mains. Its fixed now.

Comment: Somewhat, I'm pretty new and I honestly didn't understand how they would be magically linked and wondered why something like that isn't necessary but it wasn't in the example and I don't know enough to say otherwise.

Comment: From what I've read, dev-c++ is very old and outdated (i've never used it myself) .. i would suggest downloading visual studio if you're on windows, and just using gcc if you're on linux/osx. Sorry I can't help fix the problem for your IDE

Comment: I wouldn't be supprized, it seems to be lacking to me but its what my class is using.

Answer (score 1):

foo() only have definition. If you want to use a function that doesn't have a implement， Linker will give you this error "undefined reference".